# How to access special character in id attr in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have element like

```
<div id = "node-1-@" >
  <div class="region">
    accessData
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var data = $("#node-1-@ .region");
console.log(data.html())
```

This is giving error like

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #node-1-@
```

Comment: `$("#node-1-\\@ .region")`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/417d1r3w/
As said by @Satpal

Answer (score 1):

Try `var data = $("#node-1-\\@ .region");`

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\ .

[Ref](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: @ is not hard coded value. Special character will keep on change. How to write logic for this

Comment: how? can you mention an example?does your id have a specific pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the `@` special character in the selector:

```js
var data = $("#node-1-\\@ .region");

console.log(data.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "node-1-@" >
<div class="region">
  accessData
</div>
</div>
```

You can check the [jQuery **selectors documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for further details.

Comment: @ is not hard coded value. Special character will keep on change. How to write logic for this

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example? Edit your question with more details and examples.